# Cannot use sqrt in tabular

Tags: tables, math-mode

Whenever I use `\sqrt` in a tabular, I get this error:

```
! Missing $ inserted.
```

Example code to reproduce the error:

```
$\begin{tabular}{l}\sqrt{2}\end{tabular}$
```

Comment: If your tabular contains more rows and/or columns, and is mostly mathematics, it's simpler to use `array` $\begin{array}{l}\sqrt{2}\end{array}$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to put `$ $` inside the tabular:

```
\begin{tabular}{l}$\sqrt{2}$\end{tabular}
```